# Excepción producida: 'System.TypeInitializationException' en WindowsFormsApplication8.exe

Tags: c#

esta es mi clase

```
    public static SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;database=bodegacopcisa;Uid=root;psw=Murdo68736");
    public static DataSet Ds;

    public static DataTable Mostrar()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select * from usuario"),cnx);
        try
        {
            cnx.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            Ds = new DataSet();
            DA.Fill(Ds,"usuario");
            cnx.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally { cnx.Close(); }

        return Ds.Tables["usuario"];
    }
```

y este error me da

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Si te es posible, por favor pulsa en [edit] y agrega tu excepción como texto en lugar de como imagen.

Comment: tu funcion deberia de retornar un datatable y no un dataset

Comment: @Manny si devuelve un DataTable: `return Ds.Tables["usuario"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prueba asi, inicialize un Datable y un SqlDataReader para cargar la tabla

```
 public static DataTable Mostrar()
{
    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select * from usuario"),cnx);
    try
    {
        cnx.Open();
        //SqlDataAdapter DA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        tabla.Load(reader);
        //Ds = new DataSet();
        //DA.Fill(Ds,"usuario");
        cnx.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
    finally { cnx.Close(); }

    return tabla;
}
```

Comment: lo probe y me da el mismo error